# 10 ms latency with a simple topology in storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am running a simple topology which has a simple spout that emits tuples with two fields and a bolt which just acks in the execute method. These are run in two machines. With this setup and default configuration values, I get 10ms for the complete latency while both execute and process latency are .005ms. I have disabled logging as well. What could be the issue? Storm version is 1.0.

Comment: I think this is related to Storm ack mechanism. The UI show the value from tuple emit until tuple ack (at the spout) for processing latency. To actually, your tuple should be processed faster than the value shown. It take some more time for the ack (with is issued at the bolt) to be transfered to the acker-task and for the acker task to send the final ack to the spout...

Comment: Unless acks are batched, I really cant think of a reason why the ack takes almost 10ms however.

Comment: Not sure either to be honest. Just wanted to point out, that the acks add up to the latency...

Answer (score 0):

If you run your topology on several machines try to use `localOrShuffle()` grouping on your bolts. It will remove unnessasery traffic and network delay.